# AngularJS : Update A Function In RealTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, momentjs

I have in a controller:

```
$scope.timeAgoCreation = function(order) {
  return moment(order.createdAt).fromNow();
};
```

And in a view:

```
{{timeAgoCreation(order)}}
```

It return the correct value: 9 minutes ago. But this value is not updated in realtime. I have to refresh the page.

Is it possible to make it update realtime ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on this example in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HfYPE/212/)

It clearly demonstrates current date form with update each second.

**JS**

```
 function Ctrl2($scope,$timeout) {
 $scope.format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';

 }

angular.module('time', [])
// Register the 'myCurrentTime' directive factory method.
 // We inject $timeout and dateFilter service since the factory method is DI.
 .directive('myCurrentTime', function($timeout, dateFilter) {
  // return the directive link function. (compile function not needed)
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
  var format,  // date format
      timeoutId; // timeoutId, so that we can cancel the time updates

  // used to update the UI
  function updateTime() {
    element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
  }

  // watch the expression, and update the UI on change.
  scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
    format = value;
    updateTime();
  });

  // schedule update in one second
  function updateLater() {
    // save the timeoutId for canceling
    timeoutId = $timeout(function() {
      updateTime(); // update DOM
      updateLater(); // schedule another update
    }, 1000);
  }

  // listen on DOM destroy (removal) event, and cancel the next UI update
  // to prevent updating time ofter the DOM element was removed.
  element.bind('$destroy', function() {
    $timeout.cancel(timeoutId);
  });

  updateLater(); // kick off the UI update process.
 }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="time">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
   Date format: <input ng-model="format"> <hr/>
   Current time is: <span my-current-time="format"></span>    
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Just add this function in to the controller (don't forget to inject `$timeout` service):

```
function fireDigestEverySecond() {
    $timeout(fireDigestEverySecond , 1000);
};
fireDigestEverySecond();
```

`$timeout` automatically fires digest cycle after function passed in as first parameter is called so the value in view should be updated every second.

There you have working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GTbC4/).

Comment: this helped me.. Simple solution.. I feel this should be the answer

Comment: Wow. This was simpe. Yes this should be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some kind of timer to call the function periodically.

If you're looking for something specific to AngularJS, you might want to take a look at [angular-timer](http://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/index.html).

You could also look at the ticking clock example [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#writingdirectivesshortversion) and substitute your momentjs code instead of just showing the date and time.

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for a way to do the same thing using Moment.js and found [the angular-moment module](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) by urish.

It has custom Angular directives so all the code you need is an attribute ex:

```
<span am-time-ago="message.time"></span>
```